# Discord C# User Join messages

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm using Discord.Net in C#, making a bot. My bot works fantastic so far, but I want it to automatically assign users a specific role when they join a specific server. I've never actually learned any C#, only a bit of C++ so I know the basic Grammar. How would I go about this?
I'm assuming I would use UserJoined, but doing this heeds results telling me to use it before or after a += or -+ (Which I understand, but I don't understand it's usefullness in this given scenario)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You gave little information to work with but here is how to do it in all releases (so far):

This is IN the dependency map but below the "handlecommand", CommandHandleAsync or HandleCommandAsync:

```
client.UserJoined += AnnounceJoinedUser; //Hook into the UserJoined event of the client.
```

This is under the dependency map:

```
public async Task AnnounceJoinedUser(SocketGuildUser user) //Welcomes the new user
{
    var channel = client.GetChannel(/*/TextChannelID/*/) as SocketTextChannel; // Gets the channel to send the message in
    await channel.SendMessageAsync($"Welcome {user.mention} to {channel.Guild.Name}"); //Welcomes the new user
}
```

Comment: +1 on helping a separate issue. I was trying to find out the easiest way to mention a user. Thanks @Lunix46 !

Comment: I put the client.UserJoined in the HandleCommandAsync task but it doesn't work. Where am I suppose to put it exactly?

Comment: @ComyarD, Its a very long time ago since this was active. There is probably better ways to sort these things out today. If you really want to i suggest looking up if there is more effecient ways to make discord bots :)

Answer (score 1):

In case any of you wanted to send a message directly to the joining user

```
client.UserJoined += HandleUserJoinedAsync;
```

```cs
private async Task HandleUserJoinedAsync(SocketGuildUser gUser)
{
    if (gUser.IsBot || gUser.IsWebhook) return;
    var dmChannel = await gUser.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync();
    await dmChannel.SendMessageAsync("Witaj");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those who need an answer, in this period, I leave you this piece of code, just to send a message to a user's join, (1 line):

```
Client.UserJoined += join;

private async Task join(SocketGuildUser user)
{
    await (user.Guild.DefaultChannel).SendMessageAsync("Text")
    return;
}
```