# Discord Bot Event for Members Joining Channel

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I want my Discord bot to greet members when they join a channel. I have been unable to find an event that fires when this happens. I have tried `myClient.UserJoined += MyMethod;` and others but they never get fired as I hope. Here is my main code:

```
public class Program
{
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandService _commands;
    private IServiceProvider _services;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _commands = new CommandService();
        _services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_commands)
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        string botToken = // removed

        _client.Log += Log;

        await RegisterCommandsAsync();
        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, botToken);
        await _client.StartAsync();
        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
    {
        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
        _client.UserJoined += JoinedAsync; // Something like this to notify bot when someone has joined chat?

        await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
    }

    private Task JoinedAsync(SocketGuildUser arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;

        if(message is null || message.Author.IsBot)
        {
            return;
        }

        int argPos = 0;

        if (message.HasStringPrefix("!", ref argPos))
        {
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);
            await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, and let me know if I can provide any more information.

Edit: The suggested link implements the UserJoined event, which only seems to trigger when a new member joins the channel. I need something that triggers everytime anyone logs in to the channel, even existing members.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord C# User Join messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443658/discord-c-sharp-user-join-messages)

Comment: @MXD Thank you, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the edit, I think you may have a slight mis conception of how the channels work.

Users join a guild, after which, they have become part of the guild.
After they join a guild, they are part of it, and the channels they are allowed to see. Hence there is no need to *log into channels* anymore.

Now what I think you want to achieve is sending a message in a channel / to a user whenever they switch from the *offline* state to the *online* state.

For this you could use the `UserUpdated` event. Where you can check the previous and the current status of a user, and send a message accordingly.

```
_client.UserUpdated += async (before, after) =>
{
   // Check if the user was offline, and now no longer is
   if(before.Status == UserStatus.Offline && after.Status != UserStatus.Offline)
   {
      // Find some channel to send the message to
      var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("Hello-World", ChannelType.Text);
      // Send the message you wish to send
      await channel.SendMessage(after.Name + " has come online!");
   }
}
```